# Is possible to display collections(mongoDb) and each element from all collections on the same Ejs page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I'm trying to create a little forum for my website with nodeJs/Express/MongoDb/Ejs(for Html render)
When i trying to display the content of the collections i have the fabulous : "can not set headers after they are sent to the client" i don't understand .. is about to create a forum on my website like all the collections are the questions send by users and in each collection there are the comments from users and response ..

this is my code , in bottom is the part with problem .. without that all work ..
Have a nice evening

```
app.get("/vosQuestions",(req,res)=>{    
    let test = db.collection(test1.toString())
    const curseur = db.listCollections().toArray()    
    .then (result=>{ 
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html")
        res.render("vosQuestions",{collectionName :result })
        res.end()
    })
    .catch(error=>console.error(error))

// Problem part //

    test.find(function(err,results){
        if (err) throw err
        console.log("le find est :"+results)       
        res.render("vosQuestions",{TEST :results })
        res.end()
    })
})
```

Comment: for this part  `"can not set headers after they are sent to the client"` you have to use return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error: `can not set headers after they are sent to the client` because you are trying to send the response back to client again, after sending it once already.

You need to get all the required collection or documents first and then only send the response back to client. you can only send one response back.

Try this:

```
app.get("/vosQuestions",async (req,res)=>{    
    try{

        let test = db.collection(test1.toString())
        let  collectionName = await db.listCollections().toArray()   
        let tests = await test.find();
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html")
        res.render("vosQuestions",{collectionName: collectionName, TEST :tests })
        res.end()
    }
    catch(error){
        console.error(error)
//send the error response back here.
    }
})
```

Note: I have used async/await here for better readability.

Comment: That's work ! thanks you very much for your time . Have a nice day!